# How do I parse an object coming back from AWS SES SDK in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm trying to use AWS SES getIdentityVerificationAttributes via code, and I'm having trouble parsing the object coming back.

I've made a mess out of the code below, but AWS says it is coming back as a map, so I tried doing a .get() and it threw an error that .get() is not a function. So I tried working with Object.entries but still I can't find a good way of returning the VerificationStatus of this object. I expected JSON.Parse(identityVerify) to work, but it doesn't (getting "ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1").

```
const isEmailAWSVerified = async (Email) => {
    try {
        console.log('[isEmailAWSVerified] Email: ', Email);

   /*
    data = {
        VerificationAttributes: {
        "myEmail@example.com": {
        VerificationStatus: "Success", // Could be "Pending", "Failed"...
        VerificationToken: "EXAMPLE3VYb9EDI2nTOQRi/Tf6MI/6bD6THIGiP1MVY="
        }
      }
    }
   */

        let identityVerify= 
            await SES.getIdentityVerificationAttributes(
                {Identities: [`${Email}`]})
                .promise();
        
        console.log('[isEmailAWSVerified] - identityVerify', identityVerify);
        const parsedResponse = JSON.Parse(identityVerify);

        const ret = Object.entries(identityVerify.VerificationAttributes).map(([key, val]) => {
            let status = '';
            if (key === Email) {
                const tmp = JSON.Parse(val);
                console.log('[isEmailAWSVerified -- Inside Map] tmp: ', tmp);
                // status = Object.entries(val).map(([key, val]) => {
                //     return val;
                // });
                return status;
            }
            return '';
          })

        console.log('[isEmailAWSVerified] - ret', ret);
        
        return ret === 'Success' ? 1 : 0;
    } catch ( err) {
        console.log('[isEmailAWSVerified] - ERROR', err);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I found a good example in PHP -- How can I translate that to JS?

```
try:
            response = self.ses_client.get_identity_verification_attributes(
                Identities=[identity])
            status = response['VerificationAttributes'].get(
                identity, {'VerificationStatus': 'NotFound'})['VerificationStatus']
            logger.info("Got status of %s for %s.", status, identity)
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception("Couldn't get status for %s.", identity)
            raise
        else:
            return status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, we don't need `JSON.Parse`, because is an object already.
We can get verification status just by using `const status = identityVerify.VerificationAttributes[`${Email}`].VerificationStatus;`

Comment: Thanks! All it is missing is the `` to surround ${Email}.